# Dependency tracker marks activemq-broker as vulnerable

Tags: java, security, activemq-classic

I use `spring-boot-starter-activemq` with the lastest version of springboot (2.7.1). Our company's dependency tracker marks `activemq-broker` which is part of the starter as vulnerable because of CVE-2015-3208 (XML external entity - XXE). We use ActiveMQ "Classic" instead of ActiveMQ Artemis for integration with a legacy system. Is there a way to fix it or is this just a false positive? I see that that there are updates in Maven repository quite frequently ([link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/activemq-broker)) hence I can't believe that the vulnerability published in 2017 is not solved yet.